# Advice on making acrylic drop seeder

Tags: tools, cutting, gardening, acrylic

I would like to make a DIY drop seeder like the one shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTVvjtp3V8E&t=2s). I am just very inexperienced with acrylic/plexiglass as a material.

1. What thickness would you consider, looking at the video/image below?
2. How would I go about creating those circular notches on the surface?
3. Any considerations about cutting acrylic sheets?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

A drill bit will cut holes in acrylic, but don’t use acrylic or you will probably experience breakage like your example. Use polycarbonate, a name brand is Lexan. It can be purchased in the same thickness. It is usually a bit more expensive but it will not crack even when dropped, or hit with a hammer but will preform exactly the same otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see notches as much as through-holes. Acrylic is easily cut to specifications by using a CO2 laser. For the design in the video, one could get away with 3 mm thick acrylic, keeping the weight down while providing enough strength for such a device.

Ed suggests polycarbonate, which is stronger and cannot be cut with a laser.

Finding a local makerspace, or posting a query on a laser forum such as [Lightburn Software](http://forum.lightburnsoftware.com/) should find you a willing cutting resource. I've done a number of custom laser projects for members of both our local makerspace and visitors to the above noted forum.

Using a service is also a possibility, but the costs increase substantially for established industrial services one would find.

Comment: A laser to cut acrylic or polycarbonate? That's a bit overkill for DIY, no? I've worked with both with standard woodworking tools and had absolutely no problems at all.

Comment: It's an option available well suited for the task required. Good that you can work acrylic and polycarbonate with standard wood working tools. Overkill, no. Makerspaces and home-use laser cutters abound.